# Synchronization Issue In SAP CRM

Tags: javascript, synchronization, qtp

We are automating SAP CRM Website and are facing issues in synchronisation for controls.Following are few lines of code::

line 1

```
WebFrameWEclick("Browser().Window().Page()","Frame","text","0") 
'click on the webelement in webframe with text
```

line2

```
Browser().Page().SAPFrame().WebEdit().Set "Description_1234"
'enters data in WebEdit box*
```

line 3

```
Browser().Page().SAPFrame("SAP_Account_Interaction").SAPEdit().Set "123456"
```

After each line gets executed the page refreshes,but the refresh is not getting refelected in progess bar nor in status bar.
The page calls some javascript function and so the page refreshes after each line.The inner html of a edit box ::

```
<input onfocus="thtmlb_inputFocus(this);thtmlbSaveKeyboardFocus('C22_W67_V69_V79_btpartnerset_soldto_name');" onblur="thtmlb_inputBlur(this);" onchange="thtmlb_toggleInput(this);" class="th-if th-if-icon" style="width:100%;" id="C22_W67_V69_V79_btpartnerset_soldto_name" maxlength="50 " onkeydown="if(htmlbEnterKey(event)){blur(this);focus(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'C22_W67_V69_V79_btpartnerset_soldto_name:submitonenter','0')};thF4Input(event,this);" controller="ZSRQM_INCID_H" view="INCIDENTHEADEREF" pageid="C22_W67_V69_V79" svhtype="lastFive" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="thtmlbCSVHManger.svhKeyUpInputF4FieldHandler(event,'C22_W67_V69_V79_btpartnerset_soldto_name','','','','C22_W67_V69_V79', '', 'lastFive','ZSRQM_INCID_H','INCIDENTHEADEREF');" ondblclick="thtmlbCSVHManger.svhDoubleClickInputF4FieldHandler('C22_W67_V69_V79_btpartnerset_soldto_name','C22_W67_V69_V79','ZSRQM_INCID_H','INCIDENTHEADEREF');" value="">
```

I have tried the following methods but that didn't solve the problem:

1.wait statement
2.exist statement
3.increased object timeout
4.WaitProperty

```
If oBrowser.WaitProperty("state", micRegExpMatch("4|complete"), 60 * 1000) then
```

Please suggest a solution for the synchronization problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please go through the question for more details.

Comment: Here's a good answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25545625/1405898